# Inflectional words of word in 'English' language

Tags: c#, python, vb.net, postgresql

I am working on a project for migrating from Microsoft SQL Server to Postgres. In our application we have a program to retrieve list of 'inflectional' forms of a word in 'English' language which is achieved by using SQL Server's "FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "[word]")".

I am looking for similar feature in any of Postgres, C#, VB.Net or Python (NLTK). However most of the times I am getting results about stemming or lemmatization but not the reverse which is getting inflectional forms.

So can anyone suggest any 3rd party plug-ins of Postgres, C#, VB.Net or Python to get all inflectional forms of a word in 'English'?

Comment: A detail that may be important is what is the target language?

Comment: @Chillie: I am not sure about which language may completely support this. That's why I am asking any of Postgres extension or any of C#, VB.Net and Python languages. This is because we're using Postgres, C#, VB.Net and Python languages in our project. So, I am okay with any of these target languages

Comment: I meant the natural language of the words that you archive. =)

Comment: @Chillie: Oh, thanks for pointing this! I updated my question and title to include 'English' natural language.

Comment: If I understood your intent correctly, you may have some luck searching for a "morphological analyzer" and maybe "POS tagger" or "inflection engine".